# Why does foreach not compile when compiling target with es3?

Tags: typescript, foreach

I set target to 'es3' in the typescript settings.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es3",
        "outDir": "dist"
    }
}
```

And I wrote the 'foreach' syntax.

```
const array: string[] = ['hi', 'hello'];

array.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

I have compiled this code.
The following results were obtained.

```
var array = ['hi', 'hello'];
array.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Why does not the 'foreach' syntax compile with es3?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not compile"?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov

Even if you compile with es3 as the target, the foreach syntax is still foreach. Foreach is code that can be used in es5 and above.

Comment: I believe Typescript assumes polyfills are included where available, and forEach can be easily polyfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods will never be transpiled into other forms in TypeScript. If you call `.someMethod()` in TypeScript the resulting JavaScript will also call `.someMethod()`, even when there actually is no such method. Instead, `for-of` syntax will give you ES3-compatible code.

```
for (const item of []) { }
```

This gives you:

```
for (var _i = 0, _a = []; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var item = _a[_i];
}
```

An unfortunate thing is that TS does not show an error that you don't have `.forEach`, this is because the lib.d.ts contains every ES5-defined types and thinks you have them. (See [Microsoft/TypeScript#2410](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2410) for more information)